# An example on Hochschild Cohomology Groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation, deformation-theory, hochschild-cohomology

I'm starting to study Hochschild cohomology from the book of Sarah Witherspoon, “Hochschild Cohomology for Algebras”. By a lecture notes of Maria Julia Redondo, “Hochschild cohomology: some methods for computations”, I know that

> $A$ is a separable algebra over a field $F$, if and only if $HH^{i}(A, M) = 0$ for every $i > 0$, and for every $A$-bimodule $M$.

I want to read a proof of that statement. Also, I want an example of an algebra $A$ not separable over the field $F$ and an $A$-bimodule $M$ such that $HH^{i}(A,M) = 0$ for every $i = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc$

Are there other books devoted to the subject of Hochschild cohomology?